# load native web component (non angular component) inside angular web component

Tags: angular, web-component, micro-frontend

I have an angular container component named **AppComponent**. I want to load my non angular component **HelloComponent** inside **AppComponent**.

My actual goal is to load existing old components into angular 6 components.

```
export class HelloComponent extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
   }
   connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHtml = `<h1>Native component loaded successfully</h1>`;
      //init and load component.
   }
}
```

my angular code is as follows:

```
<angular-app>
     <hello-comp></hello-com>
</angular-app>
```

How do I inject this **HelloComponent** into this class.

html customElements does not work.

Comment: If @Intervalia answered your question, please accept his answer. This site is based on community recognition of contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the native component is properly defined it should load anywhere. Don't forget to call `customElements.define('hello-comp', HelloComponent);` after defining the class `HelloComponent`

I assume you are using es6 imports so you will need to import the **HelloComponent** file in your angular file.

And, Make sure you are running on a browser that supports Native Components or make sure to load the polyfill.

Comment: yes, it worked. using CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA, angular allows to use it.
I also tried 2 way communication between angular components and my hello-comp.
It worked using custom events & getters and setters methods.